# How to group data in SQL query based on the sequence of occurance

Tags: mysql, sql

See the table below you can see the dates, cls, and phs

```
Ops Day Date       St.Time  End TimeCls Phs   
A   1   13.11.2015  4:45    6:30    PP  RXXX    
A   1   13.11.2015  6:30    12:00   PP  RXXX    
A   1   13.11.2015  12:00   18:00   PP  RXXX    
A   3   15.11.2015  1:00    3:00    CN  RXXX    
A   3   15.11.2015  3:00    8:00    CN  RXXX    
A   3   15.11.2015  8:00    10:30   PP  RXXX    
A   3   15.11.2015  10:30   12:00   PP  RXXX    
A   4   16.11.2015  15:30   16:00   PP  CXXX    
A   4   16.11.2015  16:00   18:30   PP  CXXX    
A   4   16.11.2015  23:30   23:59   PN  CXXX    
A   5   17.11.2015  0:00    0:15    PN  CXXX    
A   5   17.11.2015  0:15    0:45    PP  CXXX    
A   5   17.11.2015  0:45    1:15    PP  CXXX    
A   5   17.11.2015  1:15    1:30    PP  CXXX    
A   5   17.11.2015  1:30    2:00    PP  CXXX
```

Now i want the output of the query to be like this

1. RXXX - Cls PP
2. RXXX - Cls CN
3. RXXX - Cls PP
4. CXXX - Cls PP
5. CXXX - Cls PN
6. CXXX - Cls PP

Which means if the Phs, Cls are the same within running dates then it should be group into one sequence. If the Phs have different Cls then another sequence. Or even if the Phs and Cls are the same as the previous but it comes after a different Cls or Phs. It should be group to the next sequence.

The dates is basically should make up the sequence but it create another sequence when either by phs and cls or both phs and cls are different

Expected results after it has been grouped

```
Ops Day Date    Strt Time   End timeCls Phs   Seq
A   1   13.11.2015  4:45    6:30    PP  RXXX    1
A   3   15.11.2015  1:00    3:00    CN  RXXX    2
A   3   15.11.2015  8:00    10:30   PP  RXXX    3
A   4   16.11.2015  15:30   16:00   PP  CXXX    4
A   4   16.11.2015  23:30   23:59   PN  CXXX    5
A   5   17.11.2015  0:15    0:45    PP  CXXX    6
```

Comment: This sounds like an interesting project, do let us know if you have a question!

Comment: Not a job for SQL.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT 
    *, @Seq:=@Seq + 1 AS `Seq`
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `Ops`, `Day`, `Date`, `Start`, `End`, `Phs`
    FROM
        `yourtable`
    GROUP BY `Day` , `Date` , `Cls` , `Phs`) tblresults,
    (SELECT @Seq:=0) tblSeq;
```